# How to put datepicker filter for table?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to search a `datepicker filter` for my table but all I could find are for ranges only. Is there any other way to implement the filter for this date format?

I had made this working `data-filter` and the date was somehow complicated. I tried doing the month `dropdwon filte`r but it should also be a complete date filter. If I add dropdown for dates (1-31) it would be a long dropdown.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $rows = $('tbody#report tr')

  var $filters = $('.table-filter').change(function() {
    var filterArr = $filters.filter(function() {
      return this.value
    }).map(function() {
      var $el = $(this);
      var value = $el.is('select') ? $el.find(':selected').text() : $el.val()
      return {
        col: $el.data('col'),
        value: value.toLowerCase()
      }
    }).get();
    if (!filterArr.length) {
      $rows.show()
    } else {
      $rows.hide().filter(function() {
        var $row = $(this)
        return filterArr.every(function(filterObj, i) {
          var cellText = $row.find('td').eq(filterObj.col).text().toLowerCase();
          return cellText.includes(filterObj.value);
        })
      }).show()
    }
  })
});


function selectAll() {
  var blnChecked = document.getElementById("del-cb").checked;
  var check_dels = document.getElementsByClassName("check_del");
  var intLength = check_dels.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < intLength; i++) {
    var check_del = check_dels[i];
    check_del.checked = blnChecked;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <select id="requesttypefilter" name="requesttypefilter" class="table-filter form-control" data-col="1">
      <option value="">요청유형</option>
      <option value="1">입금</option>
      <option value="2">출금</option>
      <option value="3">머니이동</option>
      <option value="4">보너스</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <select id="statusfilter" name="statusfilter" class="table-filter form-control" data-col="4">
      <option value="">상태</option>
      <option value="1">진행중</option>
      <option value="2">완료</option>
      <option value="3">취소</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input id="startdate" class="datepicker"></input>
  </div>

  <button type="button" class="hist-delete">삭제</button>
</div>
<table id="myTable" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"><input type="checkbox" name="del-cb" id="del-cb" onclick="selectAll()"></th>
      <th scope="col">요청유형</th>
      <th scope="col">금액</th>
      <th scope="col">요청날짜</th>
      <th scope="col">상태</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="report">
    <tr>
      <td class="proposalId"><input type="checkbox" class="check_del" id='check_1' name='check_1' value='1'></td>
      <td>머니이동</td>
      <td>60,000</td>
      <td>Aug 19, 2019 09:14:18</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn-action-ongoing">진행중</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="proposalId"><input type="checkbox" class="check_del" id='check_2' name='check_2' value='2'></td>
      <td>출금</td>
      <td>50,000</td>
      <td>Sept 20, 2019 09:14:18</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn-action-cancel"> 취소</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="proposalId"><input type="checkbox" class="check_del" id='check_3' name='check_3' value='3'></td>
      <td>머니이동</td>
      <td>60,000</td>
      <td>Oct 17, 2019 09:14:18</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn-action-complete">완료</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="proposalId"><input type="checkbox" class="check_del" id='check_4' name='check_4' value='4'></td>
      <td>입금</td>
      <td>60,000</td>
      <td>Sept 20, 2019 09:14:18</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn-action-complete">완료</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="proposalId"><input type="checkbox" class="check_del" id='check_5' name='check_5' value='5'></td>
      <td>보너스</td>
      <td>60,000</td>
      <td>Aug 19, 2019 09:14:18</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn-action-ongoing">진행중</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="proposalId"><input type="checkbox" class="check_del" id='check_6' name='check_6' value='6'></td>
      <td>머니이동</td>
      <td>60,000</td>
      <td>Sept 20, 2019 09:14:18</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn-action-cancel">취소</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="proposalId"><input type="checkbox" class="check_del" id='check_7' name='check_7' value='7'></td>
      <td>보너스</td>
      <td>60,000</td>
      <td>Oct 17, 2019 09:14:18</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn-action-cancel">취소</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="proposalId"><input type="checkbox" class="check_del" id='check_8' name='check_8' value='8'></td>
      <td>입금</td>
      <td>60,000</td>
      <td>Sept 20, 2019 09:14:18</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn-action-cancel">취소</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="proposalId"><input type="checkbox" class="check_del" id='check_9' name='check_9' value='9'></td>
      <td>머니이동</td>
      <td>60,000</td>
      <td>Oct 17, 2019 09:14:18</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn-action-complete">완료</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="proposalId"><input type="checkbox" class="check_del" id='check_10' name='check_10' value='10'></td>
      <td>입금</td>
      <td>60,000</td>
      <td>Aug 19, 2019 09:14:18</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn-action-ongoing">진행중</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think you should add StartDate and EndDate controls.

Comment: Isn't it for date ranges only? @Tomato32

Comment: Yeah. It's my idea. If you load all date data to drop-down list, maybe hard for users to filter data.